# PDF Rectangle[re] display position differs from object position in PDF document

Tags: pdf, adobe, pdfbox, acrobat, adobe-illustrator

There are two rectangles

[image: two rectangles]

on the page.

[**Page Contents:**](https://i.ibb.co/djHMzDP/content.png)

```
/OC /MC0 BDC
  0.087 0.963 0.488 0.002 k
  0 0 0 0 K
  /GS0 gs
  118.442 63.791 61.046 133.721 re
  B
  92.977 141.837 21.744 55.674 re
  B
EMC
```

The actual [Y position of the left *(little)* rectangle](https://i.ibb.co/sjxk6BG/left-rect.png) is higher [141.837], than right *(big)* rectangle.

[image: Y position of the left _(little)_ rectangle]

**Why do they displays like they have similar Y position?**

***P.S.***: transformation matrix [CTM] of the left rectangle is standard

[image: standart]

I tried to get actual coordinates *(from pdf page content stream)* and then put it to the new file. The result is [image: here]

I wish to know why left rectangle displays on Y=53.988 and not on Y=141.337

Comment: Couldn't you have used an image site that doesn't drown a viewer in ads? After opening the first two image links I stopped looking into this because of that.

Comment: @mkl Done. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PDF the default coordinate system is located in bottom left corner, the Y is relative to bottom margin, not top.

63+133 = 141 + 55 (same top Y)

Glad to see you are using our XFINIUM.PDF Inspector to look inside the PDF files. The PDF bounds are relative to standard PDF coordinate system, the Display bounds are relative to top left corner of the visible page area.